# send request to a servlet from JSP on loading the JSP without user input(like button)

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want to send request to a servlet "MyServlet" from a JSP "MyJsp.jsp" ,
automatically when the JSP loads,
without requiring the user to give any input like press a button etc.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a onLoad Event to the HTML page and then submit the required values using Javascript. this wil submit the values to server without user intervention after the page is load